# How to restart webxr session with all objects(only models) removed from the scene

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webxr

currently when webxr session restarts 2 X previous objects are shown on the screen , I want to show clear screen just as if session restart , currently I write this:

```
 for( var i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
                     scene.remove(scene.children[i]); 
                    }
```

This removes everything and ar functionality is lost , so how to remove only models added in webxr ( they can be of gltf or obj format) , I write this inside webxr sessionend listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to check the object type if it was group I deleted it ,

```
for( var i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
                     if(scene.children[i].type === "Group"){
                     scene.remove(scene.children[i]); 
                          }
                    }
```